# How to change nested dict key from corresponding key value

Tags: python-3.x

I have a nested dict with key as integer, I am trying to use the name from each element values as the key of the dictionary, but I had some errors.
Could someone tell me what's wrong with my code and what's the best pythonic way to achieve my goal? Thanks in advance.

```
dict=
{
    1: {
        'name': 'PLS_1-2-3-4-5-6_IPVPN_101_1',
        'qos': 'ef',
        'police': {
            'cir': '100',
            'cbs': '6400',
        },
        'marker': {
            'use-pre-set-markings': 'false',
            'cir-conform-action': 'none',
            'cir-exceed-action': 'drop',
            'pir-exceed-action': ''
        }
    },
    2: {
        'name': 'policer_RT_257',
        'qos': 'cs7',
        'police': {
            'cir': '10000000',
            'cbs': '16384',
        },
        'marker': {
            'use-pre-set-markings': 'false',
            'cir-conform-action': 'none',
            'cir-exceed-action': 'drop',
            'pir-exceed-action': ''
        }
    },
    3: {
        'name': 'PW_VPN_Test_2_PW',
        'qos': 'ef',
        'police': {
            'cir': '10000',
            'cbs': '640000',
        },
        'marker': {
            'use-pre-set-markings': 'false',
            'cir-conform-action': 'none',
            'cir-exceed-action': 'drop',
            'pir-exceed-action': ''
        }
    }
}
```

the expected

```
dict2={
    'PLS_1-2-3-4-5-6_IPVPN_101_1': {
        'name': 'PLS_1-2-3-4-5-6_IPVPN_101_1',
        'qos': 'ef',
        'police': {
            'cir': '100',
            'cbs': '6400',
        },
        'marker': {
            'use-pre-set-markings': 'false',
            'cir-conform-action': 'none',
            'cir-exceed-action': 'drop',
            'pir-exceed-action': ''
        }
    },
    'policer_RT_257': {
        'name': 'policer_RT_257',
        'qos': 'cs7',
        'police': {
            'cir': '10000000',
            'cbs': '16384',
        },
        'marker': {
            'use-pre-set-markings': 'false',
            'cir-conform-action': 'none',
            'cir-exceed-action': 'drop',
            'pir-exceed-action': ''
        }
    },
    'PW_VPN_Test_2_PW': {
        'name': 'Tef_PW_VPN_Test_2_PW',
        'qos': 'ef',
        'police': {
            'cir': '10000',
            'cbs': '640000',
        },
        'marker': {
            'use-pre-set-markings': 'false',
            'cir-conform-action': 'none',
            'cir-exceed-action': 'drop',
            'pir-exceed-action': ''
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to use key, value iteration as new list of keys, and values, then zip them as a new dictionary, but got some errors.

````
```
listOfValues = [value for (key, value) in dict.items()]
listOfKeys = [key['name'] for (key, value) in dict.items()]
dict2 = zip(listOfKeys, listOfValues)
```
````

Errors:

```
listOfKeys = [key['name'] for (key, value) in dict.items()]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict = {v['name']: v for v in dict.values()}
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that!  You should make a *list of dictionaries* rather than have integers 
as keys:

```
dictList = [
{
        'name': 'PLS_1-2-3-4-5-6_IPVPN_101_1',
        'qos': 'ef',
        'police': {
            'cir': '100',
            'cbs': '6400',
        },
        'marker': {
            'use-pre-set-markings': 'false',
            'cir-conform-action': 'none',
            'cir-exceed-action': 'drop',
            'pir-exceed-action': ''
        },
...
]
```

Now you can access `dictList` by the *index*:

```
dictList[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

First :dont use `dict` as a variable, because `dict` is a function

,so use `dict1`  for example instead

Then:the key of `dict` is int obeject

Try this:

```
 listOfValues = [value for (key, value) in dict1.items()]
 listOfKeys = [dict1[key]['name'] for (key, value) in dict1.items()]
 dict2 = dict(zip(listOfKeys, listOfValues))
 dict2
```

Output:

```
{'PLS_1-2-3-4-5-6_IPVPN_101_1': {'name': 'PLS_1-2-3-4-5-6_IPVPN_101_1',
  'qos': 'ef',
  'police': {'cir': '100', 'cbs': '6400'},
  'marker': {'use-pre-set-markings': 'false',
   'cir-conform-action': 'none',
   'cir-exceed-action': 'drop',
   'pir-exceed-action': ''}},
 'policer_RT_257': {'name': 'policer_RT_257',
  'qos': 'cs7',
  'police': {'cir': '10000000', 'cbs': '16384'},
  'marker': {'use-pre-set-markings': 'false',
   'cir-conform-action': 'none',
   'cir-exceed-action': 'drop',
   'pir-exceed-action': ''}},
 'PW_VPN_Test_2_PW': {'name': 'PW_VPN_Test_2_PW',
  'qos': 'ef',
  'police': {'cir': '10000', 'cbs': '640000'},
  'marker': {'use-pre-set-markings': 'false',
   'cir-conform-action': 'none',
   'cir-exceed-action': 'drop',
   'pir-exceed-action': ''}}}
```